# Dynamically loaded content through $.post not retaining click events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So, I'm trying to create a TODO list but I'm having problems with "click" events once I dinamically load content. 
What I want to achieve is that, once I click an element, send the "id" through $.post to a PHP file that deletes said row from my MySQL Database. And then, shows a new list without the deleted row.

Currently, I'm loading my "list.php" with $.get onto my `"#todo-list"` div. However, once I click, the info is sent, the row gets deleted, I get the new list without the deleted element. Every is ok at that point. 
However, when I click an element of my new list, nothing happenns.

This is my Javascript File:

```
$(function() {
    $.get("list.php", function(data){
        $("#todo-list").html(data);
        $("#todo").on("click", "li", function(){
            let li = $(this);
            let id = li.attr("id");
            $.post("list.php", {id: id}, function(data){
                $("#todo-list").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My test app</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
        <style>
            .todo-list li:hover {
                text-decoration: line-through;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TODO: Just a list with stuff to do...</h1>
        <div id="todo-list">
            Loading content...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
// code to connect to MySQL with PDO...
if ($_POST) {
    // code to delete the id
}
$data = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM todo");
$data->execute();
echo "<ul id='todo'>\n";
while ($row = $data->fetch()) {
    echo "<li id='{$row['id']}'>{$row['todo']}</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

As said, nothing happens after I get the new list with the deleted row.

I want my new list to be clickable, the same way the first list is... and of course, if I have 20 elements, I want to be able to click and delete them without reloading the page. Is it possible?

Comment: that's because you've replaced the `#todo` element, so the event handler is gone - try `$("#todo-list").on('click', 'li',`

Comment: If you dynamically modify the DOM you'll have to re-bind the event-handlers. New elements are not detected otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your click hanlder to delete row should be like this,you need to assign event handler again to newly added rows,

```
function delete_row(){
let li = $(this);
let id = li.attr("id");
$.post("list.php", {id: id}, function(data){
    $("#todo-list").html(data);
    //assigne the event handle again
    $("#todo").on("click", "li",delete_row)
 });
}

$(function() {
$.get("list.php", function(data){
    $("#todo-list").html(data);
    $("#todo").on("click", "li",delete_row)
});
});
```