# Click event of jquery is not working when div is dynamically created inside javascript function except on page load it is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click event of jquery is not working when div is dynamically created inside javascript function except on page load it is working.

On button click i pass month to function setCalenderMonth() which creates html fot that month and appends to  like $('#calendar').html(html);

HTML: 
    Jan 2
    Feb 1
    Mar 1

```
JS: 
    function setCalenderMonth(calenderMonth){
    let html="";
    $('#calendar > div').remove();
    html = "<div class='table-responsive-md'><table class='table table-borderless text-center' id='monthTable'><tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th>";

    for(i=0;i<=41;i++){
         // if week is over then start a new line
        if((i%7)==0){
            html += "</tr><tr>";
        }
        // if week is over then start a new line
        if((i>= first_day) && (dy<= last_date)){
            html += "<td class='monthDay'><span style='cursor:pointer;padding:2px 6px'>"+ dy +"</span></td>";
            dy=dy+1;
        }
        else {
            html += "<td></td>";
        } // Blank dates.
    } // end of for loop

    html += "</tr></table></div>";
    $('#calendar').html(html);
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.monthDay').unbind().on('click',function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
)};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically loaded content through $.post not retaining click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663393/dynamically-loaded-content-through-post-not-retaining-click-events)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('body').on('click', '.monthDay',function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
)};
```

And it will trigger all the elements that you add dynamically.

Comment: @AbidHussain what do you mean the first one is not working?